# attachment issue using php mail() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code for sending mixed content(text with html + attachment):

```
function multi_attach_mail($to, $subject, $message1, $senderMail, $senderName, $files){

    $from = $senderName." <".$senderMail.">"; 
    $headers = "From: $from";

    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    $message1 = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message1 . "\n\n"; 


    $message1 .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    $fp =    @fopen($files,"rb");
    $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($files));
    @fclose($fp);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message1 .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files)."\"\n" . 
    "Content-Description: ".basename($files)."\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files)."\"; size=".filesize($files).";\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message1 .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
    $returnpath = "-f" . $senderMail;

    $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message1, $headers, $returnpath); 

    if($mail){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
}
```

It sends email successfully, attaches file, but attachment content isn't available and once downloaded it says that file can be damaged. I guess something is wrong with my headers but can't understand exactly what is the issue.

I'm using wordpress and this function is inside theme folder's functions.php file.

Comment: used wp_mail Instead of PHP mail in wordpress
reffer link here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: again when I'm using wp_mail() file is corrupted @PriyankaPriyanka

Comment: try to use ` "\r\n" `  instead of ` "\n" `

Comment: no it doesn't help, just tried @vahid